# Send forwarded domain email to Gmail folder

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email-forwarding

I have a couple of email addresses from name@example.com that I'm forwarding to a personal Gmail account.

However, I need to save disk space and move my email messages to Gmail. Is it possible to send name@example.com email messages automatically to a label inside of my Gmail personal account instead of just lying there in the main inbox?

This way I would be able to delete my domain emails and some disk space on my hosting and I would have all the emails sent automatically to a label on Gmail.

Am I thinking correctly? I sometimes get a bit confused with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use labels for this. Gmail doesn't have folders, it has labels.

You can automatically assign a label to an incoming email via filters. The filter can even archive the email, so that it retains it, but doesn't include the inbox label. Archiving is just the removal of the inbox label.

You can also have gmail retrieve email from a third party account. That function can also attach a label and auto archive.

A cool feature of labels is that a message can have multiple labels, thus allowing you to avoid the problem of trying to store a message in two folders. You can also have the list of labels in the sidebar, making it easy to jump to a label.